# concatenate content of two files using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a textfile1 with content like below

```
s323284
s322502
s323051
s323278
s323278
```

and the second textfile2 with content like below

```
3284
2502
3051
3278
3278
```

I cant figure out using awk or sed or even on the cat command so that my output file will be like below;

```
s323284,3284
s322502,2502
s323051,3051
s323278,3278
s323278,3278
```

Need an efficient way to combine the two files especially if the content lines are in a hundred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [paste](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/upaste.htm) command

```
paste -d"," textfile1 textfile2 > outputfile
```

Comment: sweet. i overlooked the paste command. works like a charm. many thanks

Answer (score 0):

And Using [`pr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pr.1.html) command

```
pr -mtJS',' file1 file2 > outfile
```

Test Results:

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file1
s323284
s322502
s323051
s323278
s323278

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat file2
3284
2502
3051
3278
3278

[akshay@localhost tmp]$ pr -mtJS',' file1 file2
s323284,3284
s322502,2502
s323051,3051
s323278,3278
s323278,3278
```